# Using the iPhone to control a remote controlled car via Arduino

Tags: arduino, iphone, remote, control, tutorial

So i started this project a while back where i made a remote controlled car that i could control with the directional buttons on my keyboard via an Arduino ->  now the next step i want to do is to get the tilt control in my iPhone to be driving the car  :)

Anyone got a good tutorial on this?

Cheers,

Mad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest problem you've got is how to get data from the iPhone to the Arduino.  The main possibilities are to:

- Physically interface the iPod Touch/iPhone to the Arduino.  ([See this thread](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1207058161)).
- Send a signal from the iPod Touch/iPhone via WiFi (or, I believe, from the iPhone via Bluetooth) to a computer (likely running a webserver) or directly to the Arduino (provided it has additional hardware to receive bluetooth or WiFi signals.)  ([See this blog entry](http://hackedgadgets.com/2008/10/20/iphone-controlled-rc-car-using-an-arduino/)).

Answer (score 4):

At the moment i am doing something similar with a light show.

You can use TouchOSC on the IPhone to send signals to your computer which can then send them to the arduino.

My set up is IPhone(Touch OSC) -> Processing -> Arduino

Works a treat I am tidying up my code now will post a link to it if you like. -

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of stuff on controlling things with the iPhone on the Arduino forum. [Here](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=iphone&btnG=search&domains=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arduino.cc&sitesearch=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arduino.cc%2Fcgi-bin%2Fyabb2%2F) is what I found with a search.